# Using PyMySQL with MariaDB

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/switching-to-mariadb-from-mysql) about switching from MySQL to MariaDB on Ubuntu. The article claims that it would be not problem to switch between the two.

Currently, I am using [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) to connect to my MySQL database and insert, update and delete values from it.

My question is: can I just upgrade to MariaDB and keep on using my Python code? Will PyMySQL also connect correctly to MariaDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [MariaDB versus MySQL - Compatibility](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/):

> #### MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement for MySQL
>
> For all practical purposes, MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement of the same MySQL version (for example MySQL 5.1 -> [MariaDB 5.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-51/), [MariaDB 5.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-52/) & [MariaDB 5.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-53/) are compatible. MySQL 5.5 is compatible with [MariaDB 5.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-55/) and also in practice with [MariaDB 10.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-100/)). What this means is that:
>
> - Data and table definition files (.frm) files are binary compatible.
>
>   - See note below for an incompatibility with views!
> - All client APIs, protocols and structs are identical.
> - All filenames, binaries, paths, ports, sockets, and etc... should be the same.
> - All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) work unchanged with MariaDB.
>
>   - There are some [installation issues with PHP5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installation-issues-with-php5/) that you should be aware of (a bug in how the old PHP5 client checks library compatibility).
> - The `mysql-client` package also works with MariaDB server.
> - The shared client library is binary compatible with MySQL's client library.
>
> This means that for most cases, you can just uninstall MySQL and [install MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-installing-and-upgrading-mariadb/) and you are good to go. (No need to convert any datafiles if you use same main version, like 5.1). You must however still run `mysql_upgrade` to finish the upgrade. This is needed to ensure that your mysql privilege and event tables are updated with the new fields MariaDB uses.

The article goes on to list a few minor incompatibilities, which you should check your application(s) do not rely upon.